# React browser inter-page communication with iframes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe, browser, communication

I know with iframes and postMessage/eventlisteners we can send messages between the parent and their child components.

So let's say I have 2 react applications (a main, and a frame). If inside the main I load the frame as an iframe, sending data is possible. However, what I would like to do is load the 2 app in 2 distinct pages, and then send the data like that.
The url of these 2 pages is the same, except the port number (so, like: localhost:3000 and localhost:4000)

The 2 page can only know the other's url, and that's all

Now as I think about it, it brings up a lot of security question for sure, but I was still wondering if this could even be done?

Comment: Can you confirm... are you asking how to communicate between two pages that do **not** have a parent/opener relationship?

Comment: Well, yes. The only thing they know about each other is the address.
What I want to achieve is that if I changed something on page1, it would notify page2, someway like they would do it in a parent/child relationship

Comment: If this cannot be done, maybe having the iframe open in another tab, so it seemingly is 2 distinct page that have no relation to each other?